# Need Comparsion Feature in TFS to be used in Custom Application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Currently I am developing an custom tool. The requirement is as below:

Consider user wants to compare the file checked out in his machine with TFS lates version. User will go to the tool, will give the local path and server path of file. I want to provide the user this option without opneing to VS 2008. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to compare the local version to the tfs server version without opening Visual Studio?

You can use the [TF Command line utilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to get the latest version from the server and make a diff of the two files via e.g. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). Or you can make use of the `difference` command from the TF command line utilities: [Difference Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

You can also make use of [MSBuild tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) to work with TFS without firing up Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks moontear, Currently I am looking onto your comments.